# OpenGL: Avoid geometry shader for cubemap framebuffer

Tags: opengl, shaders, cubemap, frame-buffer, geometry-shader

I want to render an environment map into a cubemap framebuffer but I dislike the fact, that I have to use the geometry shader to set `gl_Layer` because the geometry shader would be a basic passthrough shader. Additionally a geometry shader could stall the pipeline and decrease performance.

I would rather like to use instanced rendering and set `gl_Layer` in the vertex shader but 
unfortunately this is only possible with the [AMD_vertex_shader_layer](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/vertex_shader_layer.txt) extension.

Is there any other way to set the layer in the shader?